# Ошибка (cannot start thread)

Tags: c#, firebird

Произвожу множественный запрос к базам данных (один и тот же запрос во всех базах данных, которые нашлись в папке).
Примерно после 134 базы данных (более 4400 баз в папках) происходит ошибка Internal Firebird Consistency Check (cannon start thread).
Упростил свою программу до одной функции, использую ее в консольном приложении, проблема все еще проявляется.
Суть программы:

Получаю список файлов.

Перебираю файлы по порядку в списке.

Для каждого файла создаю строку подключения.

Открываю коннект.

Формирую команду.

Произвожу выполнение команды в датаридер.

Перебираю записи в датаридер.

Закрываю ридер.

Закрываю коннект.

Перехожу к следующему файлу.

Как я ранее написал, примерно после 134 обработки файла, выдается вышесказанная ошибка при попытке открыть подключение к файлу.

Использую провайдер под Firebird .net [Ссылка на provider dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/2.7.7/NETProvider-2.7.7-NET35.7z/download)

Использую под VS2008 Express.

Где может вкрасться проблема?

Если необходим исходный код, могу привести пример, но мне кажется общего описания достаточно.

**UPD**

В общем, как я понял, причина никому не известна такого поведения. Попробовал исследовать 
 проблему, но так и ничего не получилось. Привожу дополнительную информацию, может кого натолкнет на мысль?..

Собственно сама ошибка в которая появляется:
[image]

Результат работы программы отражается в диспетчере задач вот так (это к окну консоли):
[image]

Исходный код программы выглядит так:
[image]

Если у вас появится идея как исправить ошибку - сообщите плиз. Пробовал также Sleep ставить в 100 и 500мс после закрытия подключения к базе и вызывать ручками dispose объектов, все не помогло =(

Comment: Закрываете с использованием метода `Close` или блока `using`? Используйте лучше второе, надёжнее.

Comment: Поскольку базы обрабабываются мультипоточно, возможно у вас заканчиваются ресурсы системы и очередной поток не может стартовать? Например из-за отсутствия ОЗУ.

Comment: Если загуглить по данному еррору, то большинство жалуется именно на ету проблему.

Comment: Создание коннекта происходи в блоке юзинг, в конце блока производится close. пробовал после метода close вызывать также dispose... в общем проблема похожа на то, что коннекты не закрываются и не хватает памяти... Можно ли как-то это отследить?

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема с конектами не в их закрытии, а в том, что их много. Добавьте логи, воспользуйтесь средствами студии, для мониторинга потоков, анализируйте память на компе и все станет понятно.

Comment: Сделал update поста

Comment: А если файлов БД всего лишь несколько в папке, 3 там допустим - норм работает?

Comment: да. после обработки 134-150 файла начинаются проблемы.

Comment: @wind, ответил на свой вопрос, завел новую тему по проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пообщавшись на форуме разработчиков .net провайдера firebird, выяснилось, что проблема оказалось в том, что сервер firebird не рвет соединение с базой до тех пор, пока объект существует в памяти.

Все что они смогли мне подсказать - научиться корректно прибивать объекты после их использования под .net. Собственно потому открыл новый вопрос по адресу: [Удаление объекта, освобождение памяти в нужное для меня время.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162881/c-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)

Данный вопрос можно считать закрытым, раз разработчики считают, что коннект должен рваться не по connection.close(), а по физическому удалению объекта.

Ошибка возникает при нехватке памяти у сервера для открытия очередного коннекта.

Comment: Проблема оказалась не в том, что я не убиваю объекты, а то, что сам провайдер их у себя хранит копию на них. Т.о. когда я убиваю коннект, он еще живет внутри провайдера в pollе.

Как оказалось, решение проблемы лежало на поверхности. Для моих нужд я опциями строки подключения выключил использования пулла коннектов и все заработало так, как мне нужно.


PS: Можно еще управлять размером пулла, но для моих реализаций этого не требуется. Достаточно странно, что авторы провайдера видя код, не заметили, что у меня данный параметр не используется, а у них он включен по умолчанию.