# Удаление объекта, освобождение памяти в нужное для меня время

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как работать с мусоросборщиком? Никогда не было необходимости самостоятельно контролировать, когда объект физически будет удален, но тут возникла проблема.

Проблема вытекла из другой: [ошибка (cannot start thread)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/156361/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-cannot-start-thread).

Суть проблемы в том, что в цикле открываются и закрываются подключения к базе данных (к разным базам, перебираются порядка нескольких тысяч баз). Как оказалось, хоть и объект создается в блоке `using() {}` даже при выходе из этого блока подключение к базе остается висеть (на уровне сервера firebird). Все подключения мгновенно разорвутся, как только приложение будет закрыто. Остается у меня один вариант, что объект хоть и закрыл соединение и вызвался автоматически метод `object.Dispose()` по выходу из блока `using`, объект все еще висит в памяти, и тем самым не дает серверу разорвать соединение с базой. На форуме поддержки .net провайдера firebird мне сказали, что нужно научиться физически прибивать объекты, а не надеяться на мусоросборщики. Вот сижу теперь и гадаю, как этой подсказкой воспользоваться. По мануалу не разобрался как пользоваться `GC.*`. Точнее разные варианты попробовал, но проблема не решилась. Может просто не умею готовить?..

Кто сталкивался с необходимостью физического прибития объектов, подскажите, как мне избавиться от него в нужное мне время, а не когда мусоросборщик сам посчитает это необходимым.

Заранее спасибо.

**UPD**

Вот что вижу на сервере

```
Server Version Info
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server Version: WI-V2.5.1.26351 Firebird 2.5
Server Implementation: Firebird/x86/Windows NT
Service Version: 2


Configuration Info
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Base File: D:\Program Files\Firebird_2_5\
Lock File: C:\ProgramData\firebird\
Message File: D:\Program Files\Firebird_2_5\
Security Database: D:\Program Files\Firebird_2_5\security2.fdb



Database Info
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of connections: 140
Number of databases: 140
```

Вот тестовая програмулина, которой проверял по вашим советам:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Dialect = 3;
//builder.DataSource = "localhost";
builder.Password = "masterkey";
builder.UserID = "SYSDBA";
builder.Charset = "WIN1251";

for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
{
    builder.Database = fileList[i];
    using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] - {1}", i.ToString("0000"), fileList[i]));
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Connected", i.ToString("0000")));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] - EXCEPTION {1}" ,i.ToString("0000"), ex.Message));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Disconnected", i.ToString("0000")));
    }
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Может это как раз тот случай, кода нужно делать unsafe код?

Comment: Вообще говоря, это странно. Для того и предназначен интерфейс `IDisposable`, чтобы можно было уничтожить объект по команде. Именно в этом методе должно разрываться соединение, а если он не был вызван явно - то в финализаторе. Если провайдер не позволяет создавать много объектов, даже прибивая их, вряд ли удаление из памяти спасёт.

Comment: @Modus, так фокус еще в том, что если закрыть приложение - то все коннекты мгновенно разорвутся... Такое ощущение, что именно объект не уничтожается... Сейчас еще появилась идея, что открывать запрос и отдельном потоке и ждать его завершения, может в этом случае, при прибитии потока коннекты все отрубятся, все же винда должна корректно вычищать память от уничтоженного потока, раз у меня не получается это сделать в одном потоке.

Comment: @KoVadim, попробовал. Заменил в вышеизложенном коде программы using на unsafe, поместил создание во внутрь его блока, остальное оставил также как написано в коде. Тоже не помогло.

Comment: Я понял, что разорвутся. Но при завершении приложения много чего может произойти, кроме удаления объекта из памяти. Грубо говоря, прибивается процесс - освобождаются все использованные им ресурсы. Скорее всего `FbConnection` держит не только управляемые ресурсы, но и неуправляемые, к которым через `GC` нет доступа.

Comment: @pincher1519
Просто заменить на unsafe, а и вызывать деструкторы явно (в с++ я бы вызывал delete/free).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема оказалась не в том, что я не убиваю объекты, а то, что сам провайдер их у себя хранит копию на них. Т.о. когда я убиваю коннект, он еще живет внутри провайдера в pollе.

Как оказалось, решение проблемы лежало на поверхности. Для моих нужд я опциями строки подключения выключил использования пулла коннектов и все заработало так, как мне нужно.

Благодарю Вас за беспокойство к моей проблеме.

Answer (score 2):

Можно порекомендовать только вставить после using и обнуления ссылки два заклинания:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

должно помочь, хотя может немного просесть производительность.

Comment: @ganouver, Попробовал не помогло... =(
Привел код программы и результат ее работы.

А можно узнать, какие объекты в приложении созданы и какие будут вскоре удалены при вызове мусоросборщика в нужной мне точке кода программы?

Comment: А смысл? Приведённый код принудительно удаляет все старые объекты. А вообще, это можно сделать с помощью `.NET Memory Profiler`. Вообще, раз `using` не помогает, копайте в другую сторону.

Comment: как-то точно можно (профайлеры памяти это используют), но я с этим дела не имел, не знаю. Как вариант обходного решения - выделить логику работы с БД в отдельный процесс и запускать новые процессы в цикле. Также, возможно, стоит посмотреть внимательнее на методы FbConnection. Может быть кроме Close есть еще что-то вроде принудительного освобождения. Еще (глупо, но может сработать) попробуйте не вызывать Close, а понадеяться на Dispose. Возможно Close освобождает не все ресурсы, но ставит метку что все сделал и Dispose не отрабатывает корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть у меня подозрение что из за этого

```
builder.ConnectionString
```

у вас объект и остаётся живым... пока билдер не прибьёте магия и не произойдёт...

для проверки попробуйте или убить билдера или инициализировать так:

```
using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(builder.ConnectionString+""))
```

Comment: Все разобрался. Скачал исходный код провайдера и пошагово побегал по нему, наблюдая что он вытворяет.